# How can I use the "Select" statment from a table with a name that contains blankspaces?

Tags: sql, select

When using this SQL query:
"Select * from table_name"

what happens if the name of the table contains blankspaces? Is there an special SQL sintax for selecting a table with a name such as "Author Code"?

Comment: Access, Oracle and SQLServer2005. It is a scary app!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on which database you are using.

- For SQL Server you can use square brackets: [My Table]
- For MySQL you can use backticks: `My Table`
- For Oracle you can use quotes: "My Table"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use square brackets SELECT * FROM [Author Code]

Answer (score 1):

Any object in SQL can have any name. You just need to put square brackets around it. `[Like this]` or `[^!@*@# EVEN THIS @#(*@#)]` or even `[SELECT]`.

I use this frequently in column aliases to make my reports purdy.

```
select
  c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name as [Customer Name],
  o.order_number as [Order #],
  o.total_amount as [Total Amount],
  o.order_date as [Date]
from
  customer c
  order o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
....
```